# Transcription software (manually) - shortcut pause/play on keyboard

Tags: transcription

I'm looking for a transcription software that helps me to trascribe manually audio file. When I write, I'd like to pause and play audio with a keyboard's button.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.audiotranskription.de/english, people say is the best.